# NodeJS Rest API sending an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am trying get posts which are created under specific category,subcategory and country.(The search mechanism might be only with category, by category and subcategory, by category and country etc...) I wrote this function inside my post controller it respond with an empty array but when i changed it to this(**the second function**) function it started to be working but it only responds posts which are created under category.

```
var async        = require('async');
var PostDal      = require('../dal/post');
var PreferencesDal      = require('../dal/preference');
var CategoryDal        = require('../dal/category');
var SubCategoryDal           = require('../dal/subCategory');
var CommentDal          = require('../dal/comment');
var UserDal           = require('../dal/user');
var Post           = require('../models/post');

exports.getPosts = function(req,res,next){
    let last_id = req.query.last_id;      
    var category = req.query.category;
    var subCategory   = req.query.subCategory;
    var country   = req.query.country;
    var query  = {};
    if (category) {
        query.category = category;
    } 
    if (subCategory) {
        query.subCategory = subCategory;
    }
    if(country) {
        query.country = country;
    }
    if(last_id)
        query._id = { $lt: last_id };

    let page = req.query.page * 1 || 1;
     let limit = req.query.per_page * 1 || 10;

     let queryOpts = {
        sort:{created_at:-1},
         page: page,
         limit: limit
     };
    PostDal.getCollection(query, queryOpts, function getPosts(err,docs){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(docs);
    });
};


//Second function
exports.getPosts2 = function(req,res,next){
    let last_id = req.query.last_id;      
    var category = req.query.category;
    var subCategory   = req.query.subCategory;
    var country   = req.query.country;
    var query  = {};
    if (category) {
        query.category = category;
    } 
    if (subCategory) {
        query.subCategory = subCategory;
    }
    if(country) {
        query.country = country;
    }
    if(last_id)
        query._id = { $lt: last_id };

    let page = req.query.page * 1 || 1;
     let limit = req.query.per_page * 1 || 10;

     let queryOpts = {
        sort:{created_at:-1},
         page: page,
         limit: limit
     };
    PostDal.getCollection({category:query.category:query}, queryOpts, function getPosts2(err,docs){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(docs);
    });
};`


//here is getCollections function from dal folder
exports.getCollection = function getCollection(query, opt, cb) {
 Post.find(query, {}, opt)
 .populate(population)
    .exec(function getpostssCollection(err, doc) {
      if(err) {
        return cb(err);
      }

     return cb(null, doc);

  });
};
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am developing a web app which allow users to see posts with filtering option. Options like to see posts created under specific category or category and subcategory etc......when the user creates post it will include category,subcategory,country and content. So i wanna filter the posts using those parameters